# Modifying multiple toggle switches dynamically in database using PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql, ajax

I have implemented a toggle switch button for a particular record in table , that changes the value of the record dynamically .

And now i want to do this for multiple toggle switches **on the same page**. How should I do it (provided that the size of table can vary)?

The database table contains 2 columns("id","value") . "id" will always be unique and the "value" will  be changed according to toggle button (on/off).

Here's my php code

```
<?php
$query=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test",$query); //test is the database here
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Multiple toggle switches</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylingButton.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch"
<?php
$query3=mysql_query("select * from testin where id=1"); //testin is the table here
$query4=mysql_fetch_array($query3);
if($query4['choice']=="off")
{
echo "checked";
}
?>>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
<div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
<div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
</label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">            
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myonoffswitch').click(function(){
var myonoffswitch=$('#myonoffswitch').val();
if ($("#myonoffswitch:checked").length == 0)
{
var a=myonoffswitch;
}
else
{
var a="off";
}

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax.php",
data: "value="+a ,
success: function(html){
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});

});
});
</script>  
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">            
$(document).ready( function(){
$(".cb-enable").click(function(){
var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
$('.cb-disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
});
$(".cb-disable").click(function(){
var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
$('.cb-enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
});
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the ajax.php

```
<?php
$query=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test",$query);
if(isset($_POST['value']))
{
$value=$_POST['value'];
mysql_query("update testin set choice='$value' where id='1'");
echo "<h2>You have Chosen the button status as:" .$value."</h2>";
}
?>
```

Here is the styleButton.css

```
.onoffswitch {
position: relative; width: 90px;
-webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
display: block; 
overflow: hidden; 
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid #999999;
border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;

}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
float: left; 
width: 50%; 
height: 30px; 
padding: 0; 
line-height: 30px;
font-size: 14px; 
color: white; 
font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; 
font-weight: bold;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
content: "OFF";
padding-left: 10px;
background-color: #2FCCFF; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
content: "ON";
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
width: 18px;
margin: 6px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 2px solid #999999; 
border-radius: 20px;
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
right: 56px;

}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
right: 0px;
}
```

**My Initial Approach**

1. I thought of assigning ids to each toggle switch however it might be difficult when the number of records in the table are not known and Also what if the size of table is very large (say 10000)?

Here is the rough sketch of [Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQzci.png) I want

P.S- I am a newbie here , so sorry for any wrong syntax :)

Comment: according to you that you want to vary your page output on the toggling on/off.

Comment: Besides that i also want to store the on/off state of each toggling switch in database as well.

Comment: yes this is also possible. Your design is not same with me.It is just like a demo but can be useful for you.

Comment: So...Do you know the solution?

Comment: yes i have clearly define what you have to do and where.....so you need to  connect database and and retrieve data properly.(always use mysqli not mysql)

Comment: mysqli refrers to mysql-improved.mysql extension is removed in PHP 7.

Comment: Well i appreciate your efforts but i am not sure where can i find your guided approach  (pardon me for that as this is  my first posted question :) )

Comment: ok then how can i help you.

Comment: well in simple terms........i have implemented a toggle switch for a particular record in table , this switch changes the value of the record dynamically . And now i want to do this for multiple toggle switches on the same page. How should i do it?